# Riemann integral and Lebesgue integral coincide for step functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

I read the textbook and it states that
"with the Riemann step functions $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, the Lebesgue integral and the Riemann integral coincide"
Can someone give some hints to this statement?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Write down by definition what a step function looks like and then calculate by definition the Riemann integral and Lebesgue integral on $[a,b]$ respectively.

---

As a concrete example, can you calculate
$$
\int_0^1f(x)\ dx\quad\textrm{and }\int_{[0,1]}f(x)\ dx
$$
where $f(x)=1_{[0,.5]}$?

Comment: How is this different that posting a comment asking if the op has tried to prove it straightforward?

Comment: @mathbeing: Am I crazy? "Can someone give some hints to this statement?"

Comment: I was not trying to say that it is not a hint. It is just that saying "hint: the straightforward approach works" doesn't look of much help. Trying the straightforward approach should have been the OP's work in the first place so anyway...

Comment: @mathbeing: I agree with you`:-)`. It was too long to be a comment and it seems that OP does not know how to get started.